# Filtering duplicate records that have a unique ID using JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am querying a badly maintained buildings database that has records similar to the following:

```
ID    NAME          CODE
54    Building A    a1234
97    Building A    a1234
```

I am querying using the following JPQL statement (where "bCodes" is an array of building codes):

```
SELECT building FROM Building building WHERE building.NAME IN (:bCodes)
```

As expected, I get back both records if bCodes = "a1234".  Is there a way in JPQL to only pull back one of the records?  I can't find a way so far - it seems that GROUP BY and DISTINCT won't work in this context.

Comment: Which would you want to pull back? Pick an arbitrary one?

Comment: It appears that most of the duplicates have everything duplicate except for the ID, so, yes, an arbitrary one.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Put it in the form of an answer for credit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend fixing your database (remove duplicates and put a unique constraint on the appropriate columns). However, to answer your question, you could further filter your query with a subquery that picks an arbitrary id:

```
SELECT building FROM Building building 
WHERE building.code IN :bCodes
AND building.id = (SELECT MIN(b2.id) FROM Building b2 
                   WHERE b2.name = building.name 
                   AND b2.code = building.code)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't fix the database.

Comment: Helpfull Thanks!