# Exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManage SELECT DISTINCT ON

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

In this line I get an error:

```
 Query query = em.createQuery(consult).setParameter("x",
 query.getResultList());
```

> Error:   An exception occurred while creating a query in
>   EntityManager:  Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT
>   DISTINCT ON(p.bote.codigo) p FROM SolicitudMembresia p WHERE p.estado
>   = 1 ORDER BY p.bote.codigo, p.fecha].  The select expression is not a valid expression.

I use JPA Eclipse Link 2.5 and Postgresql 9.4 when I rewrite without DISTINCT ON it works. In the query screen of Pgadmin  it works also.

Comment: JPQL does not allow distinct on.

Comment: Thanks. I reached my objective  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795860/filtering-duplicate-records-that-have-a-unique-id-using-jpql